# How to find Poisson Point Process in a fixed rectangle?

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to simulate a problem with MATLAB,but I must first find two-dimensional Poisson Points Process in a rectangle $[0,1] \times [-n,n]$, that $n$ is known! I don't have any information about its density $\lambda$, these points should be Poisson Points Process of any $\lambda$. I read this 
[A program for spatial point generation using Poisson processes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiouK6woprVAhUGG5oKHfo4D3QQFggyMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.leeds.ac.uk%2FStochasticRockFractures%2FDownload%2FReportsSeminars%2FReport1_POISSON_Prog.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHVfItGq3x7dymw5L7cZ62-HlIUMg)

In its 2nd and 3rd page it describes that the procedure should be the following:

The procedures for the realisation of homogeneous Poisson process in a two
dimensional region $\mathcal{R}$ are given as:

1. Sub-divide the region $\mathcal{R}$ into $m$ sub-regions, $A_1, A_2,
       …, A_m$. In most of the cases, region $\mathcal{R}$ is a rectangle
   and $A_1, A_2, …, A_m$ are disjoint rectangular quadrates with
   $\mathcal{R} = \bigcup_{i} A_i$. Work out the mean of the Poisson
   distribution for each quadrate as $\mu_i = \lambda_i \nu(A_i)$ ,
   where $\lambda_i$  is the density for quadrate $i$ and $\nu(A_i)$ is
   the area of $A_i$. For homogeneous case, $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 =
   ... = \lambda_m = \lambda$.
2. For each of the $m$ sub-regions $A_i$, generate a random variable
   $N_i$ based on the Poisson distribution function.
3. For each of the n events for quadrate $A_i$, generate two random
   variables according to the uniform distribution and use them as the
   locations inside the sub-region.
4. Repeat procedures 2 and 3 until all quadrates in $\mathcal{R}$ are
   visited

In my problem I just want to define $f$ on two-dimensional Poisson process points. if $x = (x_1,x_2)$ is a poisson point process and its projection is $y = (y_1,y_2)$ that we have for them:

$$
x_1 < y_1,\quad x_2 - 1 \leq y_2 \leq x_2 + 1
$$

And there isn't any point except two points $x , y$ in $[x_1,y_1] \times [x_2 - 1,x_2 + 1]$.It can be shown that with starting from one of the points $x$ or $y$ there exists natural numbers $m$ and $n$ that $f^m(x) = f^n(y)$.Now with this information again I don't have any idea how to choose $\lambda$.And is this homogeneous or non homogeneous problem?

Answer (score 1):

A Poisson process simply means that the probability a point is placed in any given square is the same, like raindrops falling onto floor tiles.  Well-known proofs show that the distribution of points in squares (the number of squares with $0$ points, with $1$ point, with $2$ points, etc.) then obeys the Poisson distribution formula.

So this is a very simple *Matlab* program.

But once you generate your points, you might form a histogram of the resulting set of points and fit it with a Poisson Distribution with mean $\mu$ and see how well they agree.

Comment: I don't understand how can I generate these points!

Comment: Pick a square at random.  Add a point.  Repeat.

Comment: You mean that I pick a square from $[0,1] \times [-n,n]$ at random and then I add a random point in this square?

Comment: How can I undestand that how many points should I add?

Comment: The number of points is arbitrary... add as many as you like.  But your Poisson distribution will be determined by the average number per square.

Comment: Now what do you think about my edit?